# Magento getUpSellProducts fatal error

Tags: fatal-error

I'm trying to display upsell products on product page by getting `upSellCollection` as such:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$upsell_product = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
```

After this I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUpSellProductCollection() on
>   a non-object

Any advice?

Comment: You sure you are on product page ? Which file you are working in ? Somewhere along the process, looks like you lost the registry variable for current_product.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time helping out.
I've extended view.phtml to list/upsell.phtml

Currently working on upsell.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUpSellProductCollection() on a non-object

This means your `$_product` is not an object but is a null type and you cannot call `getUpSellProductCollection()` function on null type.

**If you are in product page then your `$_product` can be just like this:**

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

Check `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` class

```
  /**
   * Retrieve current product model
   *
   * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
   */
   public function getProduct()
   {
      if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
          $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
          Mage::register('product', $product);
       }
      return Mage::registry('product');
   }
```

Now you can get your up sell product like this:

```
$upsell_product = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
```